# How to display the contents of a text file in columns

Tags: text-formatting

I have a file as follows

```
Id 123 
Name john
Lastname udosen
Tel 123456
Id 124
Name james
Lastname david
Tel 19865
```

How i can to print file as follows

```
Id     Name     Lastname    Tel
123    john     udosen      123456
124    james    david       19865
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to this site! please consider to read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formattin) and [edit] to format your question; additionally please show your efforts that you put on resolving your problem and where do you have problem to resolving it, thanks

Comment: You would use awk or perl.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want tab-delimited output:

```bsh
$ { printf '%s\n' Id Name Lastname Tel; sed 's/^[^[:blank:]]*.//' file; } | paste - - - -
Id      Name    Lastname        Tel
123     john    udosen  123456
124     james   david   19865
```

This uses `sed` to delete the initial space-or-tab-delimited word on each line (the headers). It feeds the result to `paste` which formats it into four tab-delimited columns.  The headers are added by outputting them first with `printf`.

Would you want nice-to-look-at (aligned) output, then use `column` to generate a table.  Here, I've told `paste` to insert `;` between the columns, and then I use these with `column` to align the fields:

```bsh
$ { printf '%s\n' Id Name Lastname Tel; sed 's/^[^[:blank:]]*.//' file; } | paste -d ';' - - - - | column -t -s ';'
Id   Name   Lastname  Tel
123  john   udosen    123456
124  james  david     19865
```

You could also use `csvlook` (part of [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) to generate a Markdown-formatted table in a similar way:

```bsh
$ { printf '%s\n' Id Name Lastname Tel; sed 's/^[^[:blank:]]*.//' file; } | paste -d ';' - - - - | csvlook -I -d ';'
| Id  | Name  | Lastname | Tel    |
| --- | ----- | -------- | ------ |
| 123 | john  | udosen   | 123456 |
| 124 | james | david    | 19865  |
```